# Date comparison in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I need to compare two dates/times using Bash.

Input format: 2014-12-01T21:34:03+02:00

I want to convert this format to `int` and then compare the `int`s of the two dates.

Or does bash have another way to compare two dates?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can compare [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) with the [conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) `[[ ]]` in this way:

```
[[ "2014-12-01T21:34:03+02:00" < "2014-12-01T21:35:03+02:00" ]]
```

From the man:

> [[ expression ]]
>   Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.

---

New update:

If you need to compare times with different time-zone, you can first convert those times in this way:

```
get_date() {
    date --utc --date="$1" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}

$ get_date "2014-12-01T14:00:00+00:00"
2014-12-01 14:00:00

$ get_date "2014-12-01T12:00:00-05:00"
2014-12-01 17:00:00

$ [[ $(get_date "2014-12-01T14:00:00+00:00") < $(get_date "2014-12-01T12:00:00-05:00") ]] && echo it works
it works
```

Comment: How the comparison can be done if the [[ ]] is not available in the system?

Answer (score 24):

One option would be to convert the date to the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch:

```
date -d "2014-12-01T21:34:03+02:00" +%s
```

You can then compare this integer to another date which has been processed in the same way:

```
(( $(date -d "2014-12-01T21:34:03+02:00" +%s) < $(date -d "2014-12-01T21:35:03+02:00" +%s) ))
```

The `((` `))` syntax is used to create an arithmetic context as we are comparing two numbers. You could also use the more general `[ ${x} -lt ${y} ]` style syntax if portability is a concern.

One advantage of doing it this way is that `date` understands a variety of formats, for example
`date -d "next year" +%s`. Furthermore, `date` understands timezones, so it can correctly handle comparisons between pairs of dates where the timezone is different.

However, if neither of those issues concerns you, then I'd go for [j.a.'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27429675/2088135).