# Bash - syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

I have written a script for clean Up activity based on some date condition. But I am getting an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Process Started"
Current_Date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo "todays Date ==> $Current_Date"
fromDate=$1
toDate=$2
oldDate=`date --date="3 years ago" +%Y-%m-%d`
echo "Two Yrs Back Date ==> $oldDate"
if [ $toDate -le $oldDate ]
then
find . -type f -newermt $fromDate ! -newermt $toDate -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; && echo "truncated"
else
echo "todate should be less than three years"
fi
echo "Done"
```

Getting the error - `line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file`
Although line 15 is not there script has only 14 line. Also the bash script runs fine until the command `echo "Two Yrs Back Date ==> $oldDate"`.
After that it gives the error when the `if` condition starts.
Just wanted to check any syntax error which I am making.

Comment: Quote all your vars.

Comment: the bash scripts run fine till the command `echo "Two Yrs Back Date ==> $oldDate"`  After that it gives the error when the if condition starts.

Comment: What does `bash -n yourscpript` say? Any funny characters (\r instead of \n) when you do `od -c yourscript`?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net ? Good luck.

Comment: Did you consider what happens with `if [ $toDate -le $oldDate ]` when you forget argument 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a lot of expansions that need quotes:

```
if [ "$toDate" -le "$oldDate" ]

find . -type f -newermt "$fromDate" ! -newermt "$toDate"
```

Without seeing how you invoked the script, it's hard to know whether these are contributing to your problem, but they should be fixed anyway.

You may find it helps to be consistent and quote the variables for assignment, too:

```
fromDate="$1"
toDate="$2"
```

Your script also fails at line 9, as `-le` requires an integer - you probably meant to give `date` a format string such as `+%s` to get comparable integers.

As an aside, please don't put destructive commands such as `truncate` in your example code - it should be adequate to merely `echo` or something instead.

Comment: The assignments don't need to be quoted, though it doesn't hurt, of course.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW - I've always quoted mine and didn't realise it wasn't required there.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Process Started"
Current_Date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
echo "todays Date ==> $Current_Date"

fromDate=$1
toDate=$2
oldDate=$(date --date="3 years ago" +%Y-%m-%d)
echo "Two Yrs Back Date ==> $oldDate"

if [[ "$toDate" < "$oldDate" ]] || [[ "$toDate" = "$oldDate" ]]; then
    find . -type f -newermt "$fromDate" ! -newermt "$toDate" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; && echo "truncated"
else
    echo "todate should be less than three years"
fi
echo "Done"
```

You can compare [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) with the conditional construct [[ ]] . To compare dates in bash you need to use:

```
[[ expression ]]
Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression
```

Extracted from [whoan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4095830/whoan) answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429653/comparing-dates-bash)

Is clean of warnings using [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) tool. And don't forget to quote the vars to avoid problems!! [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) is showing things like this: `^-- SC2053: Quote the rhs of = in [[ ]] to prevent glob matching`

Answer (score -1):

The operator `-le` is for comparing integers, not for strings.

Try

```
if [[ "$toDate" < "$oldDate" ]]
```

for strict less-than or

```
if [[ "$toDate" < "$oldDate" ]] || [[ "$toDate" = "$oldDate" ]]
```

for less-or-equal.

(See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: This doesn't solve the syntax error. Also, POSIX doesn't specify `<` as an operator for `[`, so you may as well use `[[ $toDate < $oldDate ]]`, because you are already relying on `bash` implementing <`. Additionally, `-o` is considered obsolete; you should use two commands joined with `||` instead: `[ ... ] || [ ... ]`.