# compare two date fields in different formats using shell script

Tags: unix

How can we compare two date fields in different formats using shell script

I have dates like this

```
Date1="mm/dd/yyyy"

Date2="yyyy/dd/mm"
```

How do I find out the difference between dates?

Comment: Why it is tagged 'hive'? Are you asking for a bash script?

Comment: @zaboj: yes I am trying in bash script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date comparison in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429653/date-comparison-in-bash)

Comment: What if my dates are in two different format like date 1: dd/mm/yyyy date2 : yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: Then use different format strings.